# MVC3 Controller issue getting JSON from HTTP POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a complicated json structure. Here it is simplified because it happens with this too:

```
{
"Id":0,
"Name":"Region Challenge",
"ModifiedOn":"2011-09-08T17:49:22",
"State":"Published",
"Goals":[
        {"Id":1,"Description":"some text here","DisplayOrder":1},
        {"Id":2,"Description":"some text here","DisplayOrder":2}
    ]
}
```

So, when this data is POST'd to controller, I have no problem getting this values for Id, Name, etc. However, Goals is null when I look at the locals window.

The signature is:

```
public JsonResult Save(int Id, String Name, DateTime ModifiedOn, String State, String Goals)
```

The POST Headers are:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:2515
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 7336
```

How do I read in the data so that I can iterate over it?

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: Goals property is not a string, it look like a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Goals` is a array or list. The simplest way is to

1. Create a viewModel
2. Change the ActionMethod

### Sample

#### ViewModel

```
public class SomeThing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public List<Goal> Goals { get; set; }
}

public class Goal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder{ get; set; }
}
```

### Changed ActionMethod

```
public JsonResult Save(SomeThing model)
{
   // model.Name ....
   // model.Id ...
   // model.Goals is your list of Goals

   // return Json
}
```

#### More Information

- [How to use the ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/08/29/how-to-use-the-asp-net-mvc-modelbinder.aspx)

Comment: Holy *(&$(*. Man, that is beautiful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

define a class like

```
public class MyClass{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string State {get;set;}
 public IList<Goals> Goals {get;set;}
}
```

your Goal class will look like

```
Public class Goals{

 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string Description {get;set;}
 public int DisplayOrder {get;set}
}
```

after that just recieved it like

```
public JsonResult Save(MyClass _MyClass)
```

you will have to include the param name like if you are sending it via ajax

```
 data:{_MyClass: yourJSON}
```